# breakpoint doesn't work on button or div element but works on li element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-devtools

I'm new to JS and trying to understand code of project https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc

Refer to screenshot, I tried to put breakpoint against `button` X , later its parent element `div` but in both cases execution doesn't stop when I click on X button. ( tried all 3 options under breakpoint )

[image]

It only worked when I put breakpoint at element `li`; chose option node removal.

Please explain what mistake am I doing here ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason the breakpoint is not working on when you are clicking on the `<button>` or the `<div>` containing the button is because there is no change to the DOM after clicking the button (seeing as the only breakpoint options, other than `on node removal`, are on `subtree modifications` or on `attribute modifications`).

The reason the `on node removal` works on the `<li>` is because (as far as I understood of the project you are using) when clicking on the button, you start a block of JS code that will remove said element (the `<li>`).

Still, if you want a way to get a way to actually add a breakpoint when clicking on the button, I suggest using this method:

- in Chrome Dev tools
- go to **Sources**
- look at the bottom half of the window and find **Event Listener Breakpoints**
- find and expand **DOM Mutation**
- enable **DOMFocusIn**
- click on your button

Caution: this will cause a breakpoint to appear whenever an element is focused (not just clicking on the button) and as probably you know some elements in the DOM can gain `focus`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: After clicking 'X' icon, DOM does get modified as whole of li data-id is getting removed. In this case why doesn't "on node removal" gets triggered ? Also *DOMFocusIn* does not work but I need to choose *click* event to see which part of code is being executed